# How to copy entire SQL Server 2008 database, applying WHERE clause to restrict copied data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, data-migration, bcp

To allow more realistic conditions during development and testing, we want to automate a process to copy our SQL Server 2008 databases down from production to developer workstations. Because these databases range in size from several GB up to 1-2 TB, it will take forever and not fit onto some machines (I'm talking to you, SSDs). I want to be able to press a button or run a script that can clone a database - structure and data - **except** be able to specify `WHERE` clauses during the data copy to reduce the size of the database.

I've found several partial solutions but nothing that is able to copy schema objects and a custom restricted data without requiring lots of manual labor to ensure objects/data are copied in correct order to satisfy dependencies, FK constraints, etc. I fully expect to write the `WHERE` clause for each table manually, but am hoping the rest can be automated so we can use this easily, quickly, and frequently. Bonus points if it automatically picks up new database objects as they are added.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot replication with conditions on tables. That way you will get your schema and data replicated whenever needed.

This [article](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-%E2%80%93-configuring-the-replication-%E2%80%93-part-5/72/sql-server-%E2%80%93-configuring-the-replication-%E2%80%93-part-5) describes how to create a merge replication, but when you choose snapshot replication the steps are the same. And the most interesting part is **Step 8: Filter Table Rows.** of course, because with this you can filter out all the unnecessary data to get replicated. But this step needs to be done for every entity and if you've got like hundreds of them, then you'd better analyze how to do that programmatically instead of going through the wizard windows.

Comment: Thanks. On your recommendation I'm reading up on this and setting up a test replication. Another in-house suggestion I'm investigating is using RedGate Virtual Restore to quickly mount the previous night's backup and then use SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare (both of which we already own) to save projects that will copy all schema and filtered data to a new database we can then copy to developer workstations.